# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-table-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I'm getting the following error quite often on my Azure Web App:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Unable to connect to
>   the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to
>   the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt
>   was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access
>   permissions {Microsoft IP Number}:443

It looks almost like something is quite actively blocking my table storage request.

Anyone know what could be going on? Am I hitting some limit? Is there some Web.config connection tweaks I have to do?

The code I'm executing:

```
var table       = AppConfiguration.Account.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference("Comments"); 
var comments    = table.CreateQuery<Comment>().Where(c => c.PartitionKey == Key).ToList<Comment>();
```

Note thate it is working 95% of the time. Just at some moments it seems to be instable for a period of time (about half an hour).

**Update**

In my logs I also see that SQL is having the same kind of connection problems around that period of time:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An
>   attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access
>   permissions.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005):
>   An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions

Am I hitting some kind of outbound connection limit on my Web App?

Another note: this Web App is hosted in North Europe, while the SQL and Table Storage are hosted in West Europe. Could that be the cause or should this be without influence?

Comment: Well... you might want to edit your question to show the code you're executing to connect to storage. Also, have you confirmed that your storage connection string and key are properly set and being read by your code? (note: I might be stating the obvious but... When you edit, please do *not* include your real connection string / key).

Comment: Hi @DavidMakogon, thanks for your quick answer. I've added the example - it's relatively straightforward as you can see.

Comment: @Dirk, Try to add your public ip to sql server port settings on Azure.

Comment: Hi @Dev, how would explain that same problem with Table Storage?

Comment: Please check the updated answer, your table storage service is not running that's why your getting that error.

Comment: @Dirk it seems that the issue is related to port, can you please add your public i.p to "SQL Server" & thereafter check? This is just to configure your Azure firewall & port setting.

Answer (score 0):

What is the mode of the SQL Azure (or SQL Server is on the VM?)? I would go with the netstat, but if it is going on not locally, troubleshooting can be a little longer process.

Placing your app and database in the different region should not be a problem.

Comment: Hi @Alexandr, what do you mean with what mode? We're using SQL Azure v12. Is that what you mean? This only seems to happen on production at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure the **"Table Service"** for the solution is running. To check it's status when running the Azure solution two icons appear in the system tray labelled. It is the development storage we are interested in. To prevent this error simple start the Table Service. That's all.

Good luck & hope that helps!

Comment: Hi @Dev, thanks for your answer. It's probably not that clear from the question, but we're talking production here - running in the cloud. Local everything runs fine.